# Command not found, although it is in the $PATH

Tags: shell, hash, path-variables

My system does not find `phpunit`, although it is definitely in my `$PATH`.

I am using ubuntu 16.04.
Here is my PATH, which contains `/usr/local/bin`

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

`composer` and `phpunit` both lie in the same directory:

```
$ which composer;which phpunit
/usr/local/bin/composer
/usr/local/bin/phpunit
```

but when i call them, `phpunit` is not found althogh `composer` is found... since `composer` is found, my path should be okay...

```
$ composer --version;phpunit --version
Composer version 1.4.2 2017-05-17 08:17:52
-bash: /usr/bin/phpunit: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
```

when I call it with the entire path the which command says, it works....

```
$ /usr/local/bin/phpunit --version
PHPUnit 6.2.3 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
```

and I don't have an alias:

```
alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'
alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
alias grep='grep --color=auto'
alias l='ls -CF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias ls='ls --color=auto'
```

am i missing something here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Drop the bash's executables locations hash

Run
`hash phpunit`

### Explanation:

There was a `phpunit` binary in `/usr/bin/` folder (as can be seen from the error message).

Now it has been moved to `/usr/local/bin/`.

But bash stored the previously found locations of executables and doesn't update them immediately, so the old `/usr/bin/phpunit` location should be cleared for the new one to be found.

Check [this ServerFault answer](https://serverfault.com/a/276898) for more info.

Comment: very interesting; didn't know this. the sad thing is, that - based on the answer in the link you've provided - i just needed to restart my putty :(

Comment: @emfi Yep, this would work as well. "Have you tried turning it off and on again" is always a useful technique to try :-)